# Change my code to only count rows with spesific value in a cell

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

How i can change my code to count only columns with a specific value in a column.

```
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
        ->select('COUNT(*)')
        ->from('#__zoo_item');
```

Is this making my code much more slow? Is there a better way to do it? It will help if i enable cache in this joomla module because the script runs in my homepage :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with getting data from the database, based on a specific column value. This is what the `where` clause is for. Like so:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select('COUNT(*)')
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__zoo_item'))
      ->where($db->quoteName('state') . ' = 1');
```

Also note I've used `$db->quoteName()` when defining column names which is used to escape them.

Hope this helps

Comment: What do you mean by escape them? I tried without it and it works!

Comment: It's used to prevent SLQ injections by escaping characters that have a special meaning in SQL. It should be done for columns (`$db->quoteName()`) and values (`$db->quote()`). It will work without but it's safer to do it with.

Comment: You mean something like ->where('select'); which select is used by mysql itself?

Comment: `where->('COLUMN_NAME') so you need to escape `COLUMN_NAME` as shown in my answer. Have a read of the Joomla Documentation for database queries to guide you a little more ;)

Comment: Yeah i got this! I am trying to understand that special meaning in mysql!